# Insert transparent flash file on page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, transparency

I have an animation transparent flash file, this file should be full screen,

In this animation I have a bird which should fly from left to right, this action is on flash file and I published the flash file in transparent mode,

Now I should insert this SWF file on top of all layers.

I can do this by `div` and `position` but when I click everywhere of this page I will get default flash menu.

How can I limit the flash menu to just visible area ?

UPDATE:
I mean was full width,

the HTML code which Flash created for me is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled-1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#">TEST</a>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1280" height="853" id="Untitled-1" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Untitled-1.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="false" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Untitled-1.swf" width="1280" height="853">
                    <param name="movie" value="Untitled-1.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="false" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your flash is full screen then the menu will also come on full screen! and can you paste you html here?

Comment: Sorry, I mean of full screen was full page, I mean my flash should be show in full width of window.

Comment: please paste your html here

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui I updated my question, before I found some javascript code for doing this

Comment: remove `height: 100%' this will make it full width not full width and height

Comment: I don't have CSS yet, important thing is when every where of this page  I will right click the flash menu will show, while the flash file is transparent and there is no a visible object

Answer (score 0):

Well, I if you want your menu to be disabled then you can't do that wit html or js but you can do that in your flash file using **actionscript** like this:

```
Stage.showMenu=false;
```

Or you can disable right click on your webpage like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

**AND**

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Flash is tranparent , but it is on top of the HTML. Clicking will generate a click event on the Flash element, blocking the other things on your website.

With jQuery it's easy to get around this.
You will need to get the coördinates of the click event and then trigger a click on the page HTML element which has the same coördinates.

```
$('#flashContent').click(function(e){
    evt = e || window.event;

    // make flash disappear
    $('#flashContent').hide();

    // get element at point of click
    starter = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);

    // send click to element at finger point
    $(starter).click();

    // bring back the flash
    $('#flashContent').show();
});
```

This will work in most cases. Remember to include the jQuery library in the `head`section and wrap this function within `document.ready` function if you aren't using jQuery allready.

Note: For right clicking you should make a similar function to this one. Instead it will listen for a right click event.

Hope it helped you out.